# Should I block Googleusercontent.com?

Tags: web-crawler, user-agent

I get many requests from this domain by different user agents, should I just block it all together or there may be consequences to it?

Comment: I think [webmasters.se] would be a better fit for this question. Stack Overflow is for programming related problems, not site management.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it fits better on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming but managing a website.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://en.wiki-domains.net/wiki/googleusercontent.com) article, this CDN saves your content on different servers throughout the world in order to have users load the Contents of the web page from a server that is closer to him. This will reduce the load times of your users. Thus, one consequence might be longer load time of your visitors.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you should block it. It is abusive.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong, but If you are making such a claim, please back it up by providing sources. Don't just make arbitrary comments. Thanks.